# Rooting Motorolla X2 adb shell problem

Tags: rooting, motorola-droid-x, adb, shell

i tried [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1234907) tutorial and in step 1 i followed method 2. I try step 3, and when i try

`adb shell` it works fine. but the line after,

`sh /sdcard/motoroot-step1.sh`, I get

`sh: Can't open /sdcard/motoroot-step1.sh`

Why is this happening?

Comment: I guess it worked after you switched off usb mass storage? please do let us know how you got on :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot execute either binary or shell script that resides on the external sdcard due to the execute permission bit being blocked.

<s>Either move the script temporarily to a location other than sdcard (**if you're not rooted** - *you're in a bit of a spot there*...)</s>

After reading the posting on xda, it would appear that something is amiss, notify the developer of that forum and post it there and see what response you get :)

***Edit:*** You have that external sdcard treated as mass-storage device. Turn that off and see what happens (***Had to read all of the thread and some one posted - see #18 there!***)